# JitPack.io does not pull up the library! Why?

Tags: java, github, gradle, dependencies, jitpack

I have an old 12 year old project that I want to redo. I added `Gradle` to the project. Now I need to add a library from `GitHub` to the project (using `Gradle`), and I saw such a thing as `JitPack`. I configured and ran everything, but the library still doesn't pull up. What is the problem?

Gradle:

```java
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.opensourcephysics.cabrillo'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.OpenSourcePhysics:osp:master-SNAPSHOT'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Library from `GitHub`:

[image]

All my libraries:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What JitPack does is build your project and leverage the artifact on the fly when gradle asks for it. But for this to happen JitPack need to build the project in the repository you're asking for.

JitPack supports project such as `gradle` project, `maven` projects etc... check this [link](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/blob/master/BUILDING.md) for a more detailed list of supported projects.

The repository you're trying to use `OpenSourcePhysics/osp` doesn't have a build script or anything like that, which makes it impossible for JitPack to build it and provide the artifact resulting for the build.

Comment: Thank you! I build jar file for this library and its work!